# Enabling and disabling spring batch listeners

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Is there any way in spring batch to enable and disable listeners.i.e without removing the configuration from context i should be able to control.Can anyone help me with this

```
<batch:job id="JobA" restartable="true">
        <batch:step id="abcde">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="Reader" writer="Writer" processor="Processor" commit-interval="10" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        <listeners>
            <listener ref="customStepListener" />
            <listener ref="customItemReaderListener" />
            <listener ref="customItemWriterListener" />
            </listeners>
 </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Without removing the configuration from context is there any way i can disable the listeners from listening.Like flag kind of thing which enables or disables the listeners.Currently my listeners are used for logging job details at read write and step level.I dnt want to do log for some instances

Comment: what do you mean by enable and disable ?

Comment: Please provide some context code.

Comment: I had edited my question.Can you please check @hdost ,@RafikBELDI

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is provided in-build in spring batch that will disable a listener that is configured.

However you could always wrap any logic you write with

```
if (enabled) then do
end if
```

Comment: But that will not actually stop the listeners from listening.It just stops the listener method from doing its job right @saifuddin

Comment: That is correct. There is no way to disable the listener without removing it from config

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the JavaApi (JobBuilder/StepBuilders) to build your job? Depending on a property you could decide which listeners to add and which not:

```
SimpleStepBuilder builder = stepBuilderFactory.get(STEP_NAME)
                .<InputDto, OutputDto>chunk(100)
                .reader(myreader)
                .writer(mywriter);
if (conditionForListener1) {
   builder.listener(mylistener1);
}
if (conditionForListener2) {
   builder.listener(mylistener2);
}

return builder.build();
```

I know that it takes some time to get familiar with the JavaApi to build SpringBatches. But the effort is worth it, because you can build your whole job completely dynamically.